# Volley string request post parameters always null in php.

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am sending a string POST request with some parameters but in PHP script i'm always getting parameters value as null. When i test the PHP with postman its working fine.

this is my volley request code:

```
public void login(final String mPhone, final String mEmail, final String mPassword) {


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getBoolean("error")) {
                        String error = jsonObject.getString("message");
                        if (error.equals("new user")) {
                            registerUser();
                        } else {
                            showProgress(false);
                            Snackbar.make(mOtpView, error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                showProgress(false);
                Snackbar.make(mOtpView, error.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("phone", mPhone);
                params.put("email", mEmail);
                params.put("password", mPassword);

                return params;
            }
        };
        //Method to limit retry policy of request
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(
                new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2,
                        3,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
                )
        );
        try {

            //Adding request to request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and this is my PHP:

```
require_once 'DbConfig.php';

$response = array();

if (isset($_GET['apicall'])) {
    switch ($_GET['apicall']) {
        case 'login':

            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $pass = $_POST['password'];

            echo $phone.$email.$pass;exit();
```

i have tried adding header by overriding getHeaders() and also tried overriding getBodyContent() but nothing seems to work and also the above code is working fine when im using it in localhost. i checked the URL its fine because the PHP script is fine as i have tested it by echoing other things it executed fine.

Comment: check if this $_GET['apicall'] is null

Comment: it could be the proccess not enter to echo statement

Comment: also check from android side using Log that you're actually sending data or not

Comment: @Urvishrana my getParams() method is invoking and it is initializing the map and returning it successfully

Comment: @HamzaNig apicall in not null as when in echoing anything else it is coming in response as it is

Comment: @DeepeshTiwari check trim it could be a space on $_GET['apicall'] : switch (trim($_GET['apicall']))

Comment: if still the same problem try to echo anything to see if you are access to case login or not

Comment: @HamzaNig code under switch statement is executing so the the $_GET['apicall'] is working as intended. in case 'login': if i echo('test'); i get the test in response in android so this is fine dont know why this code is working everywhere but android... the same code is working if i test it with localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!!! Cant think about this ever!! actually i was using URL like:- http://www.example.com but when i tried http://example.com .. it worked as charm... thanx everyone for their help though!!

Answer (score 0):

Usauly this problem could be from Content-Type add charset=utf-8 to it :

```
 params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
```

Credit : [Volley-POST-EMPTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846969/android-volley-post-request-not-working-online)

Comment: did'nt work now dont know what to do else also tried adding   params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); but the problem is same always getting null.

Comment: also tried custom request ... that too didnt work... everything is working fine with postman and localdb with android but not working when the file hosted on web and i try to send request there.

Comment: try insted of Request.Method.POST use Request.Method.Get  to see if the problem on both or just post

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending ;

`params.put("phone", mPhone);
  params.put("email", mEmail);
  params.put("password", mPassword);`

How about the;
`params.put("apicall","YOu_API");`

I guess `apicall` is not isset, so the values will be null.

Comment: apicall is header which goes with url and i am using the value given in it  to execute right case i.e. login, register.